# docker type needed to build .netcore app

Tags: .net-core, cloud-foundry, concourse

I am using concourse to deploy a .netcore app the problem i am having is that i need to run `dotnet publish --configuration release` get the resulting publish folder and publish it to cloud foundry.

what can I use instead of this for a docker image that would provide me with what i need?:

```
platform linux
image: "docker:///_______"   //using node img here for something else.
inputs:
   - name: my-resource-1
outputs:
   - name: my-resource-2
run:
   path: my-resource-1/files/pub-dotnet.sh
```

What can I add instead of the node image i am currently using for something else to be able to run this:

-- file pub-dotnet.sh

```
dotnet publish --configuration release
```

Comment: check  [Official images for .NET Core](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/)

Comment: Also, you should use the [image_resource](https://concourse.ci/running-tasks.html#image_resource) option, it is much more efficient.